# strange error in razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this:

```
<tr class="@(item.Id == (int)(Session["Id"] ?? 0) ? 
   "sfs-selected sfs-selectable" : String.Empty)">
```

but I get this meesage:

```
operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'method group' and 'int'
```

but I already cast to int.

If I do this:

```
 <tr class="@if (item.Id == (string)(Session["id"] )) {@("sfs-selected sfs-selectable") } @string.Empty ">
```

then I get this error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.
```

So how to check on null value?

Thank you

if I do this:

```
 <tr class="@(item.Id == (Session["Id"] ?? 0) ? "sfs-selected sfs-selectable" : String.Empty)">
```

I get this warning:

Warning as Error: Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cast the right hand side to type 'string'

So I do this:

```
<tr class="@(item.Id == (string)(Session["Id"] ?? 0) ? "sfs-selected sfs-selectable" : String.Empty)">
```

then I get this:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.
```

Comment: It seems like razor means item.Id is a method group

Comment: Can you put the full view?

Comment: public string Id { get; set; }

Comment: What's the value of item.Id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should either remove (int) type cast or make Id as int.
see this fiddle.

https://dotnetfiddle.net/1LmsTm // Showing Error

https://dotnetfiddle.net/ka4Y59 // Changing ID to int from string

https://dotnetfiddle.net/LhsiM3 // removing int from type cast with ID as string

Comment: Hi Jitendra, but your first example is still giving an error with string as id. And also with the cast in it.

Comment: Yes, In that I am showing that if you take Id as string it's gives error, so you have to change it to int which is in second example.

Comment: I added one more fiddle with Id taking as string. Have a look & let me know.

Comment: Hi Jitendra, yes, thank you. But see my post. I had that

Comment: I get then the following error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.String'.

Comment: Check the third link in my answer, In the question, you have written (string)(Session["Id"] ?? 0) but it should be (string)(Session["Id"] ?? "0")

Comment: You have to type cast 0 as well

Answer (score 2):

The Id in item is a string and that is why you get this message. Remove the cast of the int or change the type of Id to int.

Comment: If it were a string the error message would be "[...] to operands of type 'string' and 'int' [...]"

Comment: @greenhoorn in the comments the OP identifies it as a string.

Comment: Yes, sorry. I wrote the comment before he did :D

Comment: I Edit the the post> I removed the cast

Answer (score 2):

If you do not want to make id as int then change like this and try

`(item.Id == (Session["Id"].ToString() ?? "0") ?`

Comment: remove the semicolon and try again I just posted the sample code. please modify according to your requirement.